# Is there a way to show the description defined in dsl at admin endpoint

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

The description is for a human to read. I want the stub runner boot application users to see those descriptions directly at the admin endpoint. Is there a way to do this?

Or other recommended ways to use spring contract more efficiently, make the communication more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to store the contracts under src/main/resources/contracts, change the plugin to point to that directory and then write an actuator endpoint that will print the contents of the contracts